# MFC SDI app: do work automatically after UI is shown

Tags: mfc

I have an existing (legacy) SDI app, and I want to call some functions immediately after the UI is shown, i.e. when it would normally sit idle and wait for user input.

Normally I'd put the calls in CView::OnInitialUpdate, e.g.:

```
CMyView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CView::OnInitialUpdate();
    //...

    LoadStartupData(); //<-- this is what I want to call

}
```

... but this gets executed before the UI is shown. For this I want to show some UI feedback while it runs (it takes a while and should probably be in its own thread, but that's a different problem); the function also shows a dialog at the end of it, so I do need the UI to be visible.

What's the "best practice" on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PostMessage in your init code with a WM_APP+x message.

When the message pump runs your message is delivered to the window and you can do your lazy init.

Use a ON_MESSAGE(MY_WM_APP_INIT,OnMyInit) entry in the message map.

Other way would be to use CWinApp::OnIdle, but this isn't view specific.

Or use a "one time" Timer... start a timer handle it and kill it.

Comment: Regarding the PostMessage approach - Does this guarantee the message gets received after the UI gets shown? (assuming I'm not adding other unusual message processing code, of course)

Comment: If you use UpdateWindow in InitInstance and because the message pump starts after InitInstance, the answer is yes. If you don't use UpdateWindow the result may be some kind of random. Usually all messages are processed before WM_PAINT messages are generated. But parts of your application are surely visible because you called ShowWindow... But this is academic. Why must this message arrive AFTER your window is shown?

Comment: Mainly I want to make sure the app isn't stuck in LoadStartupData waiting for some modal dialog, while the whole thing is not yet visible to the user -- which was the problem I had with OnInitialUpdate.

Anyway, my InitInstance does call UpdateWindow, so I guess that ensures WM_PAINT gets enqueued before my messages from OnInitialUpdate.  Thanks for the explanation!